# Optional Parameter is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to set up a route that has an optional parameter status.
This is the route:

```
app
    .route('/trips/:status?')
    .get(getManyTripsCommand)
```

this is the function:

```
async function getManyTripsCommand(request, response) {
    console.log(request.params)
    const status = request.params.status

    try {
        const trips = await getManyTrips(status)
        return response.status(201).json(trips)
    } catch (err) {
        return response.status(err.code).json({ status: err.code, message: err.message })
    }

}
```

and this is the request:

```
localhost:3002/trips?status="active"
```

in getManyTripsCommand, request.params.status is undefined. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query` instead of `params`

```
request.query.status
```

Here are more details:
https://stackabuse.com/get-query-strings-and-parameters-in-express-js/